# Horizontal scrolling on overflowing image - HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, scroll

I currently have a site with a landscape-oriented image (the map image in the code below) on it; a simple landing page. The site is to be responsive, so I currently have the image as `height: 100%` so that it always fills up the browser window. I set the `width: auto` so it keeps proportions, but the image falls of the screen. Trying to do a `overflow:scroll` doesn't do anything, and I'm unable to scroll horizontally, making my image cut off. Here's my markup and styles (in Sass):

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="map" src="rvagetsit_map_edit.png" alt="RVA Gets I.T."/>
<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="rvagetsitlogo.png" alt="RVA Gets I.T."/>
</div>
```

```
body {
min-height: 100%;
position: fixed;
overflow: scroll;
.container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    #map {
        position: fixed;
        width: auto;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        overflow: scroll;

    }
```

As you can see, I tried to use overflow in a few instances but it didn't work. Basically, I just want the height to fill the browser window, but be able to scroll horizontally to see the rest of the image.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: get your css syntax sorted first.  remember to close your curly brackets `body{}` [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<style type="text/css">
.container {
height: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;    
white-space: nowrap;
width: 100%;
}
#map {
height: 100%;
vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img id="map" src="rvagetsit_map_edit.png" alt="RVA Gets I.T."/>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

HTML

```
<div class="slideshow">
   <div class="images">
       A slideshow of images in here (whatever you want to say for screen readers)
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.images {
  background: url(slideshow.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 300%;
  -webkit-animation: slideshow 10s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:    slideshow 10s linear infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
@moz-keyframes slideshow {
  0%    { left: 0; }
  100%  { left: -200%; }
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/[enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/infinite-all-css-scrolling-slideshow/)